# AWS ECR Lifecycle Policy is not executed but works in test

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr, buildx

I set images Lifecycle policies to delete untagged images and images with a specific prefix

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "rulePriority": 1,
      "description": "Delete untagged images",
      "selection": {
        "tagStatus": "untagged",
        "countType": "sinceImagePushed",
        "countUnit": "days",
        "countNumber": 1
      },
      "action": {
        "type": "expire"
      }
    },
    {
      "action": {
        "type": "expire"
      },
      "selection": {
        "countType": "sinceImagePushed",
        "countUnit": "days",
        "countNumber": 5,
        "tagStatus": "tagged",
        "tagPrefixList": [
          "staging"
        ]
      },
      "description": "Delete old staging images",
      "rulePriority": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I clicked "test rules" and dryRun shows all the affected images correctly. But it actually didn't delete any untagged images even after I waited for several days. What could be the reason? Why does it work in "test", but doesn't work for the repository itself?

The untagged images are created by `docker buildx` for multiple architectures. Like leftovers after the buildx pushes.

Comment: could you solve this problem? As for me, I tested my rules in the test area it seemed it would delete a lot of images, then I moved the test rules to the active rule area and I expected the rules to immediately delete images but it didn't. The deletion started about 20 minutes later but it worked as expected.

Comment: @atavio how do you move it to "active rule" area? I dont see such option. Only to test rules. But otherwise those rules just sit there doing nothing.

Comment: Hi @Andrius, I just selected the test rule and clicked on the "Apply as lifecycle policy" button.

Comment: Interesting, I dont see such option. Though when I was moving it as test policy and back, after some time it started working. AWS workflow is kind of unintuitive..

Answer (score 3):

According to the [first paragraph in the Lifecycle policies user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/LifecyclePolicies.html)

**Affected images may take up to 24 hours to expire**.

S3 life cycle policies also have the same behavior.